# If statement with 2 possible numbers

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Hey all i am probably overthinking this but how can i check the textbox for either a 655 or 699 in the first 3 numbers in the textbox?

The current code i how now works but displays an error if (im guessing) it doesnt find the other number in the textbox as well:

```
 If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(txtNumber.Text, 1, 3) <> 655 Or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(txtNumber.Text, 1, 3) <> 699 Then
 'ERROR
 end if
```

What would i be doing incorrectly?

David

Comment: Try `And` rather than `Or`.  Or, even better, `AndAlso`.  And if you care at all about type safety or semantics, put those "numbers" in quotes.

Comment: The cause of your error is almost certainly when the text box doesn't contain enough characters.

Comment: @SpectralGhost: Not an issue.  If the string doesn't have >=3 chars, you'll just get whatever's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
If Left(txtNumber.Text, 3) = "655" OrElse Left(txtNumber.Text, 3) = "699" Then 
   ' good?
End if
```

Although it looks like you might want an error if it's not either one, in which case just wrap the two test above in paran's and put a Not before them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to want to use Left, not Mid if it's the first 3 characters.

Second, you're checking a string against an integer.

Third, you're checking if it's not those 3 characters when I'm guessing you want to check if they are equal, so you'll want to change that, as well.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    If Mid(txtNumber.Text, 1, 3) <> "655" And Mid(txtNumber.Text, 1, 3) <> "699" Then
        'Code
    End If
```